# How to fix TypeError in a Solidity contract?

Tags: contract-development, contract-debugging

I am having issues with getting the contract below to compile.

Here is the contract I am trying to compile in Remix IDE. The issue has been commented below <--- ISSUE IS HERE.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.6.12;
//pragma abiencoder v2;

import './MyToken.sol';
import './Initializable.sol';
//import './SafeMath.sol';
import './IERC20.sol';
import './IFactory.sol';
import './IPool.sol';
import './ISettlement.sol';
import './IOracle.sol';
import * as symbol from "./IPool.sol";
import * as decimals from "./IPool.sol";
import * as totalSupply from "./IPool.sol";
import * as balanceOf from "./IPool.sol";
import * as getAmountOutFromValue from "./IPool.sol";
import * as getValueFromAmountIn from "./IPool.sol";

contract Pool is Initializable {
    using SafeMath for uint;

    bytes4 private constant SELECTOR = bytes4(keccak256(bytes('transfer(address,uint256)')));

    address public factory;
    address public baseToken;
    uint public baseTokenDecimals;
    address public oracle;
    uint public oracleDecimals;
    

    uint public baseTokenTargetAmount;
    uint public baseTokenBalance;

    uint public liquidityParameter;

    bool public tradeEnabled;
    bool public depositEnabled;
    bool public withdrawEnabled;

    uint private unlocked;
    modifier lock() {
        require(unlocked == 1, 'HalbornSwap: LOCKED');
        unlocked = 0;
        _;
        unlocked = 1;
    }

    modifier tradeAllowed() {
        require(tradeEnabled, "HalbornSwap: TRADE_NOT_ALLOWED");
        _;
    }

    modifier depositAllowed() {
        require(depositEnabled, "HalbornSwap: DEPOSIT_NOT_ALLOWED");
        _;
    }

    modifier withdrawAllowed() {
        require(withdrawEnabled, "HalbornSwap: WITHDRAW_NOT_ALLOWED");
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyRouter() {
        require(msg.sender == IFactory(factory).router(), 'HalbornSwap: ONLY_ROUTER_ALLOWED');
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyFactory() {
        require(msg.sender == factory, 'HalbornSwap: ONLY_FACTORY_ALLOWED');
        _;
    }

    event Mint(address indexed sender, uint amount);
    event Burn(address indexed sender, uint amount, address indexed to);
    event AmountIn(address indexed sender, uint amount);
    event AmountOut(address indexed sender, uint amount, address indexed to);
    event EmergencyWithdraw(uint256 _timestamp, address indexed _token, uint256 _amount, address indexed _to);

    function init(address _factory, address _baseToken, address _oracle, uint _liquidityParameter) external initializer {
        factory = _factory;
        baseToken = _baseToken;
        baseTokenDecimals = IERC20(baseToken).decimals(); // <--- ISSUE IS HERE
        oracle = _oracle;
        oracleDecimals = IOracle(oracle).decimals();

        tradeEnabled = false;
        depositEnabled = false;
        withdrawEnabled = false;

        liquidityParameter = _liquidityParameter;

        symbol = string(abi.encodePacked("CS-", IERC20(baseToken).symbol()));
        decimals = baseTokenDecimals;

        unlocked = 1;
    }

    function _safeTransfer(address token, address to, uint value) private {
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = token.call(abi.encodeWithSelector(SELECTOR, to, value));
        require(success && (data.length == 0 || abi.decode(data, (bool))), 'HalbornSwap: TRANSFER_FAILED');
    }

    function mint(address to) external lock onlyRouter depositAllowed returns (uint liquidity) {
        uint balance = IERC20(baseToken).balanceOf(address(this));
        uint amount = balance.sub(baseTokenBalance);

        if (totalSupply == 0) {
            liquidity = amount.add(baseTokenTargetAmount);
        } else {
            liquidity = amount.mul(totalSupply).div(baseTokenTargetAmount);
        }

        require(liquidity > 0, 'HalbornSwap: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY_MINTED');
        Mint(to, liquidity);

        baseTokenBalance = baseTokenBalance.add(amount);
        baseTokenTargetAmount = baseTokenTargetAmount.add(amount);

        emit Mint(msg.sender, amount);
    }

    function burn(address to) external lock onlyRouter withdrawAllowed returns (uint amount) {
        uint liquidity = balanceOf[address(this)];

        amount = liquidity.mul(baseTokenTargetAmount).div(totalSupply);

        require(amount > 0, 'HalbornSwap: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY_BURNED');

        require(baseTokenBalance >= amount, 'HalbornSwap: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY');

        Burn(address(this), liquidity);
        _safeTransfer(baseToken, to, amount);

        baseTokenBalance = baseTokenBalance.sub(amount);
        baseTokenTargetAmount = baseTokenTargetAmount.sub(amount);

        emit Burn(msg.sender, amount, to);
    }

    function swapTo(address _sender, address _fromToken, uint _amountIn, uint _value, address _receiver) external lock onlyRouter tradeAllowed returns (uint maxAmount) {
        require(_fromToken != baseToken, 'HalbornSwap: INVALID_POOL');

        address pool = IFactory(factory).getPool(_fromToken);
        require(pool != address(0), 'HalbornSwap: POOL_NOT_FOUND');

        // Check if has pendingSettlement
        address settlement = IFactory(factory).settlement();
        require(!ISettlement(settlement).hasPendingSettlement(_sender, address(this)), 'HalbornSwap: PENDING_SETTLEMENT');
        
        // maxAmount because amount might be lesser during settlement. (If amount is more, excess is given back to pool)
        maxAmount = getAmountOutFromValue(_value);

        ISettlement.Settlement memory pendingSettlement = ISettlement.Settlement(
                pool,
                _amountIn,
                IPool(pool).baseTokenTargetAmount(),
                (IPool(pool).baseTokenBalance()).sub(_amountIn),
                IPool(pool).liquidityParameter(),
                address(this), 
                maxAmount,
                baseTokenTargetAmount,
                baseTokenBalance,
                liquidityParameter,
                _receiver,
                block.timestamp.add(ISettlement(settlement).settlementDuration())
            );

        // Subtract maxAmount from baseTokenBalance first, difference (if any) will be added back during settlement
        baseTokenBalance = baseTokenBalance.sub(maxAmount);

        // Add to pending settlement
        ISettlement(settlement).addSettlement(_sender, pendingSettlement);

        // Transfer amount to settlement for escrow
        _safeTransfer(baseToken, settlement, maxAmount);

        return maxAmount;
    }

    function swapFrom(address _sender) external lock onlyRouter tradeAllowed returns (uint amount, uint value) {
        uint balance = IERC20(baseToken).balanceOf(address(this));

        require(balance > baseTokenBalance, 'HalbornSwap: INSUFFICIENT_SWAP_AMOUNT');

        // Check if has pendingSettlement
        address settlement = IFactory(factory).settlement();
        require(!ISettlement(settlement).hasPendingSettlement(_sender, address(this)), 'HalbornSwap: PENDING_SETTLEMENT');

        amount = balance.sub(baseTokenBalance);
        value = getValueFromAmountIn(amount);

        baseTokenBalance = balance;

        emit AmountIn(_sender, amount);

        return (amount, value);
    }


    function getOraclePrice() public view returns (uint price) {
        (, int answer,,,) = IOracle(oracle).latestRoundData();

        // Returns price in 18 decimals
        price = uint(answer).mul(10 ** uint(18).sub(oracleDecimals));
    }

    // Swap Exact Tokens For Tokens (getAmountOut)


    // Helper functions
    function setFactory(address _factory) external onlyFactory {
        factory = _factory;
    }

    function setTradeEnabled(bool _tradeEnabled) external onlyFactory {
        tradeEnabled = _tradeEnabled;
    }

    function setDepositEnabled(bool _depositEnabled) external onlyFactory {
        depositEnabled = _depositEnabled;
    }

    function setWithdrawEnabled(bool _withdrawEnabled) external onlyFactory {
        withdrawEnabled = _withdrawEnabled;
    }

    function setLiquidityParameter(uint _liquidityParameter) external onlyFactory {
        liquidityParameter = _liquidityParameter;
    }

    function emergencyWithdraw(address _token, uint _amount, address _to) external onlyFactory {
        _safeTransfer(_token, _to, _amount);

        emit EmergencyWithdraw(block.timestamp, _token, _amount, _to);
    }
}
```

The error that is returned when trying to compile is;

```
HalbornPool.sol:84:29: TypeError: Member "decimals" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract IERC20.
        baseTokenDecimals = IERC20(baseToken).decimals();
                            ^------------------------^
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to be able to fix this issue? I have spent two days so far but cannot work out why this error is occurring since IERC20, baseToken and decimals are all declared at the beginning of the Pool contract.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The error shows you that "decimals" not found or not visible. Check the IERC20 file (ERC20 Interface) if it has the decimals function otherwise you need to add it. you need to do something like this

```
function decimals() external view returns (uint8);
```

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/IERC20Metadata.sol#L26

Comment: Thanks for responding sh -x, do you know if anything would prevent the decimals function from being read from the IERC20 file? The function is present but appears to not be visible to the main contract.

Comment: Similar to IERC20 metadat on openzeppelin, you could just create a new interfaceX and import ierc20 to it and add only the decimals() to the interfaceX. then import both IERC20 and interfaceX to the main contract. InterfaceX is an optional extension.